# Cannot enable calendars and reminders in iCloud

Tags: icloud, macos, contacts, calendar, reminders

I am using late 2014 retina macbook pro 15 inch but first when i click the iCloud settings it takes 15 seconds to open it. When I enable the contacts, I can't open the Contacts app it says contacts quit "unexpectedly".When I try to enable Calendars, I get a dialog box asking if I want to merge calendars on my Mac with those on my other devices and I get the spinning icon with the "Setting up..." text and after a few minutes, nothing happens and the checkbox is left unchecked. When I try to enable Reminders, I get a spinning icon to the right saying it is "Setting up..." and then after several minutes it does nothing and the checkbox is left unchecked (no dialog box reporting any problems).

I tried everything, logged out and logged in iCloud several times, tried to add accounts to calendar and reminder separately but nothing works.

Does anyone know the whats going on with the iCloud?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to connect my personal hotspot then enable contacts, calendar and reminders so it worked but i don't know why.

Comment: Exactly same problem here! What do you mean by hotspot?

Comment: I did it that to change the ip of my macbook. The first think in my mind is the connect my macbook to my iPhone trough the hotspot so, I got a internet connection over the cellular. Finally yo can try to change your ips